# How do I assign a record from an arbitrary block of memory?

Tags: delphi

I have the following C++ code, but I'm stuck on how to do the equivalent of `t = *(test *)&memory;` in Delphi.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct test
{
    char a, b, c, d;
};

int main() 
{
    char memory[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    test t{};
    cout << "Before: " << t.a << t.b << t.c << t.d << endl;
    t = *(test *)&memory;
    cout << "After: " << t.a << t.b << t.c << t.d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before:     
After: abcd
```

http://ideone.com/5y0jzs

Comment: struct -> record, array -> array, cast -> cast.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan could you translate `t = *(test *)&memory;` to Delphi? Pretend you have a Delphi record and a Delphi array

Comment: Well, of course I could. But isn't it better for you to learn how to do it yourself. Do you know anything about Delphi? About records, arrays, pointers and casts?

Comment: I know the concepts of records, arrays, pointers and casts from C/C++ but I don't know the correct Delphi syntax, hence I'm asking for it, to learn.

Comment: Where is your code that translates as much as you can into Delphi? Please don't make us write the entire program for you.

Comment: Just define a pointer type: `PTest = ^Test;` and now you can cast: `T := PTest(@Memory)^;`. You'll have to write the rest yourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What are you talking about? I want one line, not an entire program, I know how to write the rest. Wouldn't make sense to write the example in Delphi when it a) doesn't run and b) doesn't express what I want to achieve

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thanks

Comment: Because then we'd have the data types in Delphi. For all we know, you don't know how to do that. So giving you just the one line wouldn't help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
type
  PTest = ^Test;
  Test = record
    a, b, c, d: AnsiChar;
  end;
const
  Memory: array[0..3] of AnsiChar = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
...
  T := PTest(@Memory)^;
```

That's it.
    ...

Comment: so I always have to declare a pointer type for any type? I can't just inline it like in C/C++?

Comment: a valid question and a nice answer :-)

Comment: If you want to cast, you should have a pointer type handy. So yes, almost always. That is because of the different type system. In C++, pointers that have the same structure are considered compatible. In Delphi (and Pascal in general), this isn't so. In Delphi, types can not be declared inline (well, with the exception of certain generic types).

Comment: You can use `Move` to avoid having to declare pointer type. Or you can use a value cast rather than a pointer cast, `T := Test(Memory);`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thanks, actually that was the only thing I was stuck at, I don't know how long I would have tried fiddling that thing inline somehow

Comment: @David: yes, often it can be done without the pointer. But the problem with direct casts is that sometimes the compiler complains (e.g. with floating point types, or when the target is not the same size) and sometimes a conversion takes place. A pointer cast is often the easier method, and the generated code is normally the same as for a direct cast. I usually don't bother to think if a direct cast could work and just use the indirect one.

Comment: When the value cast works it checks that the types are the same size. In this case that's a big advantage.